# checking time with preceding zero

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on app. It has a form and one of the field is for time. Users will enter time in 24 hours format. When users enter time like `07:40` then it works fine but when they enter `7:00` then it does not. So what I want is to when `7:00` is entered then I want to add 0 before `7`. **Note** I am already removing `:` from time and making it like `700`. Now I want to add leading zero if the user has not enter anything before it and if they enter a number at the start then leave it as it is. How can I achieve this in javascript? I know I can use regex but any sample would be helpful.

Here is how am I doing but seems incorrect because it does not work.

```
var regex = /^\b(0(?!\b))+/g;

if (!regex.test(time)) {
    time = '0' + time;
}
```

Comment: hi , you can use like this...

var t= '700';
if(t.length==3)
 t= '0'+t;
alert(t);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to slice of the last *n* digits from an already prefixed string. If you want to make sure your string is always 4 digits, you could do:

```
time = ('0' + time).slice(-4);
```

Assuming you know that `time` is always at least three digits. To be sure, you could of course write:

```
time = ('0000' + time).slice(-4);
```

but that probably doesn't make much sense in your specific use case.

This code could be executed without any prior checks, not just conditionally in the case of an expression being matched.

Comment: exactly and this is also less memory demanding than regex (in this case)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it before removing the colon like this:

```
time = time.replace(/^\d{1}:/, '0$&');
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do just fine:

```
var time = '7:50';
time = time.replace(/\b\d\b/g, '0$&');
```

Before you remove the colon.

Answer (score 0):

If you are very specific with your regex expression there is no need to get fancy with prepending the 0

```
if( /^[0-9]:[0-9]{2}$/.test( time ) ) {
    time = "0" + time;
}
```